# Received DeclarationError when calling other contracts file name and its function

Tags: solidity, truffle-contract, truffle-compile

So I created 2 contracts where the first one will be the app logic contract and the other one is the database contract. So I tried to "truffle compile" my contract but receive DeclarationError.

here is the sample code of my modifier function

```
modifier requireRegisteredAirlines()
{
    require(flightSuretyData.checkAirlineRegistered(msg.sender) == true, "Caller is not registered Airline");                                       //calling the registered airline from data contract
    _;
}
```

So the flightSuretyData is my database smart contract in the same folder. and the checkAirlineRegistered is the function in that contract.  down here is the error I received

[image]

Did I leave anything?

Comment: Can you please show more of your code?

Comment: Ok I have found the problem, it is because I overlooked the "import" on top of my contract to import contract